# How to disable debug assertion dialog visual studio or on the output exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How to disable the assertion dialog in visual studio or on the output executable.
I am working with c++.

When running my executable I get the Debug dialog with options Abort/Retry/Ignore

I have already tried without success the following options:
no success even after log off:

### option 1:

Clear Managed, Native, or Script in the Just-In-Time debugging under tool options

### option 2:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework

change DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting to 1 (hex) from 10 (hex)

### option 3:

1. Start Registry Editor and locate the following Registry subkey in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE subtree:
   \SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CURRENTVERSION\AEDEBUG
2. Select the Debugger value.
3. On the Edit menu, click String.

•   To use the Windows debugger, type windbg -p %ld -e %ld.
•   To use Visual C++ 4.2 or earlier, type msvc -p %ld -e %ld.
•   To use Visual C++ 5.0 or later, type msdev.exe -p %ld -e %ld.
•   To use Dr. Watson, type drwtsn32.exe -p %ld -e %ld. You can also make Dr. Watson the default debugger by running this command:drwtsn32.exe -i.
4.  Choose OK and exit Registry Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Debug dialog with options Abort/Retry/Ignore appear only in Debug version of a program. First you can try is to compile application in Release. Second option is to redefine ASSERT macro that make this dialog to appear. Of course, these options work only if you have your application in source code and able to recompile it. Since you have application in binary, you can only hack this binary in place when messagebox is called to force to skip messagebox call.
Update: it seems you try to use options that affect CLR (.NET) applications. When using unmanaged C++, it has no effect. See project properties->C/C++->General->Common Language Runtime support option. If it is empty or "No support", you using clear unmanaged C++

Comment: However, I want a robust solution which in addition to assertion disable NULL access and other crashes

Comment: If you want something, try asking for it. It is quite different situation when application run into memory acces violation or unhandled exception and so on. Debug assertion is jus a warning that just inform you that something wrong or maybe not. Access violation is a serious error that usually unrecoverable. Unhandled exception can be caught by try-catch blocks and requires knowing your program, i.e. you just have to screw up you bugs.

Comment: Well, in situaltion when app just crash, you can run another process that monitors it and watches it to finish. After finish, return code can be analyzed.