# How to programatically disable assertions in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, assertions, unittest++

I must debug unit tests (we're using UnitTestPP) in C++ (specifically using VS 2015) and I want to disable assertions for specific sections of the code for which we're willingly making the tested code throw exceptions, which in turn makes some assertions fail, so that I'm not always clicking "ignore" each time the "assertion failed" popup appears.

I don't want to disable assertions completely since they still could be useful in signaling problematic cases in the code.

I know about the #define NDEBUG, but it doesn't work. I think this is because the unit tests are in another project/DLL.

Also, the failing assert is a ATLASSERT, I don't know if this changes something.

Comment: When an assertion fails, regardless of the cause, you have a bug.

Comment: `ATLASSERT` is a Microsoft thing, and is [documented by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7kdewh9.aspx). It's often a good idea to look at the documentation of something, when one wonders what functionality does that something have.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316665/how-to-disable-debug-assertion-dialog-visual-studio-or-on-the-output-exe

Comment: Visual Studio ships with source code for ATL. If you want to see how `ATLASSERT` is implemented (and thereby find ways to disable it), you have all the tools you need. If you do find out, that it cannot be disabled at runtime, you can use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) to monitor dialog creation, and use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) to dismiss it where appropriate.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Considering the tests in question are trying to provoke error cases it is totally expected that both exceptions are thrown and asserts don't pass. It is not the best practice to do both, but this is the harsh reality of legacy code.

Comment: @TommyD;  You wrote "which in turn makes some assertions fail". That's bugs. A unit test can make assertions fail by intentionally introducing bugs such as failed preconditions. As I recall most unit test frameworks are somewhat deficient in supporting those test cases. Some people therefore redefine the effect of assertion to exception throwing for the purpose of testing. But regardless, a failed assertion is a bug. It /can/ be an intentional bug for purpose of testing. But if it's caused by an exception, then it's a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf An assertion only means what the programmer who put it there meant, no more no less. Saying it's always a bug is dogmatic. For instance, testing to retrieve an element on an empty homemade container from a legacy code base might both trigger an exception and a raise failed assertion. The code still works as intended although the assertion is irrelevant due the presence of the exception.